# Proof using the definition of the limit of a sequence

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Prove from the definition of the limit of a sequence that $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{2n^2+\cos(n)} {n^2+1} = 2 $$

(that is, for a given $\epsilon > 0$, find an explicit $N_\epsilon$)

Please explain

I choose $n_0$ such that ${n_0} > \sqrt {\frac{3}{\varepsilon }} $. Then How can I say that for all $n\ge n_0$, we have $\left| {\frac{{2{n^2} + \cos n}}
{{{n^2} + 1}} - 2} \right| <\varepsilon$. ? How to prove this last part ?

Comment: Please edit the question to include a description of what you've tried and where you're stuck.  This will help people give useful answers at an appropriate level.  Also, I'm sure you mean $n\to\infty$, not $x\to\infty$.

Comment: I did that please recheck

Comment: Actually you did not (otherwise, please explain how you came with the idea that $n_0\gt\sqrt{3/\varepsilon}$ was okay).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have
$$\left| {\frac{{2{n^2} + \cos n}}
{{{n^2} + 1}} - 2} \right| = \left| {\frac{{\cos n - 2}}
{{{n^2} + 1}}} \right| \leqslant \frac{{\left| {\cos n} \right| + 2}}
{{{n^2} + 1}} \leqslant \frac{3}
{{{n^2}}}$$
Let $\varepsilon>0$. We choose $n_0$ such that ${n_0} > \sqrt {\frac{3}{\varepsilon }} $. Then for all $n\ge n_0$, we have $\left| {\frac{{2{n^2} + \cos n}}
{{{n^2} + 1}} - 2} \right| <\varepsilon$.

Comment: Do I need to prove this as well  ? $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{2n^2+\cos(n)} {n^2+1} = 2 $$  ?

Comment: How can we say that for all $n\ge n_0$, we have $\left| {\frac{{2{n^2} + \cos n}}
{{{n^2} + 1}} - 2} \right| <\varepsilon$. ? How to prove this last part ?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** $$\bigg|\frac{2n^2 + \cos n }{n^2  +1} - 2\bigg| = \bigg|\frac{2n^2 + \cos n  - 2n^2 - 2}{n^2  +1}\bigg| = \bigg|\frac{\cos n -2 }{n^2  +1}\bigg|\leq \frac{1 + 2}{n^2  +1} \leq \frac{3}{n^2} $$

Comment: Do I need to prove this as well  ? $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{2n^2+\cos(n)} {n^2+1} = 2 $$  ?

Comment: What do you mean? You are going to use the hint to prove that.

Comment: How can this be proved using the hint. I am not getting any way to proceed further. Please do help

Comment: For any given $\epsilon > 0$ you want to find $N \in \mathbb N$ such that $$n > N \implies \bigg|\frac{2n^2 + \cos n}{n^2 + 1} - 2\bigg| < \epsilon$$

Comment: And you may find $N$ using the hint.

Comment: like $N^2 = (\frac{3}{\epsilon})$ for $\epsilon > 0$ IS that correct ?

Comment: Notice that $$\frac{3}{n^2} < \epsilon \implies n^2 > \frac{3}{\epsilon} $$

What $N$ must be then?

Comment: okay So I must keep $n^2 > \frac{3}{\epsilon}$ ?